# Connecting Basys 3 to my MacBook pro 2019

Tags: vivado

I'm an electrical engineering student who is learning to code VHDL using Vivado, I have encountered a problem connecting my Basys 3 to my computer. Since my computer doesn't have any USB 3.0 output I have to use a USB hub that converts my USB-C to USB 3.0 . When I open HW manager in Vivado it doesn't see my Basys 3. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the hub powered? Are you sure the hub works? Have you installed all the drivers?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the hub works, I have been using my USB mouse with it, I have tried installing drivers from the driver manager but it still doesn't recognize Basys 3

Comment: You are using Vivado on a MacBook. There is no documentation that says Vivado works with Mac. If you're using an emulator inside Mac OS, then you get into the complexities of giving that emulator direct access to the USB.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying before, I have installed Windows so that I can run Vivado

Comment: Have you tried other usb3 devices?. If you are using windows, in the device manager, can you see devices appear and dissappear as you connect/disconnect them to the hub>?

Comment: Also, This sounds like a driver installation issue. I'm not sure it lives in Electrical Engineering.